# Al momento de ingresar datos con EF me sale el error que està en el cuerpo. El mismo codigo funciona en un mismo proyecto, pero no en capas

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework, webapi

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

```
namespace Controlador
{
    public class ControlCrearUsuario
    {
        DbModelo Md;
        public ControlCrearUsuario(DbModelo Md)
        {
            this.Md = Md;
        } 
        public void Guardar(Entidades.Usuario usuario)
        {          
            Md.Usuarios.Add(usuario);
            Md.SaveChanges();          
        }
    }
}

namespace Modelo
{
    public class DbModelo:DbContext
    {     
        public DbModelo(DbContextOptions<DbModelo> options):base(options) 
        { 
        }
        public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba agregar a `DbModelo` la siguiente función: `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder){}`

Comment: Aún me sigre presentando el mismo problema.

Comment: Agregue una mejor explicación del problema , a que se refiere con que no funciona en capas? Es cuando ejecuta algún comando? La cadena de conexión esta en algún appsettings.json?

Comment: Si, la cadena de conexión la tengo en el appsetting.json de dbmodelo, hice una migración y creé la base de dato y todo. El problema me surge cuando intento agregar datos a la tabla USUARIO.

Comment: Ya pude resolver muchas gracias por su ayuda.